# Understanding sampling rate and frequency of logic analysers

Tags: sampling

Below shown is the screenshot of the GUI for Saleae logic analyser http://www.saleae.com/logic

I would like to know what is the meaning of "number of samples to collect" and "sample rate" ?

[image]

As per my understanding, sample rate is how often samples are collected. Here it is shown 16MHz. so that means in one second, there are 16 mega samples collected.

[image]

But then what is this "1 M samples" ? Is it 1 million samples per second (but then what is 16MHz) ?

Or is it like this

1. in one second, we sample 16 Mega times
2. and in each of this 16 Mega sample, we will take 1 Million samples ?

Please correct me. I am so much confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leftmost setting it the total number of samples per capture while the rightmost option selects the sampling rate.

**1M samples, @16MHz** : will gather 1M samples total with a rate of 16M samples per second. That means that the capture duration will be (1/16)=0.0625 second (1M/16M)

**16M samples, @16MHz** : will gather 16M samples total with a rate of 16M samples per second. That means that the capture duration will be (16/16)=1 seconds (16M/16M)

**32M samples, @16MHz** : will gather 32M samples total with a rate of 16M samples per second. That means that the capture duration will be (32/16)=2 seconds (32M/16M)

Choosing a different sampling rate

**5M samples, @1MHz** : will gather 5M samples total with a rate of 1M sample per second. That means that the capture duration will be (5/1)=5 seconds (5M/1M)

Comment: Does this mean that 16M samples, @16MHz has a capture duration of 1 second and after 1 second, the measurement will stop ?

Comment: @robomon Yes, that is why I wrote in the reply for 16M/16M that the duration will be 1sec

Answer (score 0):

The 16 MHz refers to the sample rate while the 1 MHz is the actual number of samples taken.  At a rate of 16 million samples per second, it takes 1/16 of a second to accumulate 1 million samples. Thus there is a tradeoff between sample rate and the number of samples.  For a fixed sample rate, the sampling time is proportional to the number of samples.